# Can't import ViewModel while using Koin library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, koin

After, restart Android Studio with invalidate cache, and clean + rebuild build, I still can't import `ViewModel` class from `Koin` library. Even forcing manually the `import org.koin.android.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel` import.

[image]

app / build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:1.0.2"
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:1.0.2'
    ...
}
```

Anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your activity must extend AppCompatActivity instead of Activity.

If you want to use koin with activities, fragments or services your class must implement implement KoinComponent.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use AppCompatActivity instead Activity

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (also when the Activity extended AppCompatActivity), but in my case, the solution was in using stable version of core-ktx:

```
// Stable version - Works fine with koin and koin's viewModel
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1"

// Alpha version - When in use viewModel is not found
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: I had the same issue and using stable version worked

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Koin library dependency to use by viewmodels method . You only need to ensure that you have these dependencies :

```
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
```

Please follow this android studio guide for more info : https://androideveryday.com/2020/03/07/android-studio-guide-to-viewmodel-livedata-2020-edition/